# Is it possible to export an Animate and Plot in a grid together?

Tags: plotting, export, animation

I have a code that produces an Animate graphic and two Plots in a Grid. I am able to export the Animate graphic using .avi, but do not know how or if its possible to export these together in one file. I have tried using

```
Export["animate1.avi",Grid[a1,a2]]
```

as it was the only thing I could think of that might work, but it didn't. Also looked through the documentation and StackExchange boards and couldn't find anything...

Is this possible to do? And, if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some thing like this:

```
plot = Animate[
  Grid[{{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 2}], 
     Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2}]}, {Plot[Sin[x] + a x, {x, 0, 2}]}}], {a, 
   0, 10}]

Export["m.avi", plot]
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you.